# How to configure xUnit Mock for Prism Application?

Tags: xamarin.forms, unity-container, prism, xunit

I am new to xUnit and with the help of `Prism Template Studio` I created new Prism `xUnit` test project, which by default created one `PrismAppMock.cs` file as below:

```
 // This should implement your application class -- What does it means?
    public class PrismAppMock : PrismApplicationBase
    {
        public PrismAppMock(IPlatformInitializer initializer)
            : base(initializer)
        {
        }

        protected override IContainerExtension CreateContainerExtension()
        {
            return null;
        }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {

        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {

        }
    }
```

On running the test it is throwing null exception as container is not resolved.

I tried to use `UnityContainerExtension` but as it is abstract class I can't use it directly.

```
 protected override IContainerExtension CreateContainerExtension()
        {
            return new UnityContainerExtension();
        }
```

Can anybody suggest on how to initialise `PrismAppMock` for unit testing.

Comment: Can you clearify what exactly you're trying to achieve? What do you want to test?